# CMake reports GCC is broken. Where do I start?

Tags: gcc, cmake

I am trying to compile a project, but CMake stops right at the beginning with the message that gcc is broken (see below). I am ignoramus when it comes to CMake, so any help where to get me starting debugging this problem is very very welcome.

- GCC (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) **4.6.3** (I checked that my GCC compiles a 'hello world' problem)
- CMake version **2.8.7**
- CMake command: `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../Mantid`

**Output to terminal:**

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 
>   -- Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong. 
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 -- **broken** 
>  CMake Error at
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52
>   (MESSAGE): 
>    **The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc-4.6" is not able to
>   compile a simple testprogram.**

It fails with the following output:

> Change Dir:
>   /home/jmborr/devel/mantidproject/mantid/Code/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec/fast"
>
> /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build
>
> make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/home/jmborr/devel/mantidproject/mantid/Code/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
>   /home/jmborr/devel/mantidproject/mantid/Code/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
>   1
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>
> /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/include -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
>   /home/jmborr/devel/mantidproject/mantid/Code/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>
> **gcc-4.6: warning: /usr/include: linker input file unused because
>   linking not done**
>
> Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec
>
> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>
> /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/include /usr/lib
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTryCompileExec
>   -rdynamic
>
> **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/include: File format not
>   recognized**
>
> **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib: File format not recognized**
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory

Answer (score 5):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296360/yet-another-cmake-error-the-c-compiler-yagarto-is-not-able-to-compile).

I had the same problem. I think the problem is that you need more parameters to compile (like linker-script, flags ...). Change your CMakeLists.txt like this and try it again:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(g++ GNU)
```

Do not forget to set the path to the compiler in your environment variables.

Comment: It's not that. I found that the problem is constrained to my account. I made a new user account and I could compile from this account.

Comment: Ok. so that means your last account didnt have admin-rights to access and execute the compiler?? right!

Comment: yes, it had. I was compiling one day with no troubles and the next day I couldn't do a thing. Go figure :( I even disabled my .bash_aliases but didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Same happened with me, in CLion.

Check if your compilers and other things are properly installed and/or configured.

I Re-installed the GCC Compiler and the CMake, then reconfigured my IDE.

and it worked for me since then!