# C compiler broken with cmake

Tags: cmake, cygwin, gnu-make, vtk

I know a similar question was asked already here [cmake reports gcc is broken. Where do I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594053/cmake-reports-gcc-is-broken-where-do-i-start)
However there was no real answer on that post so since I'm also stuck with that I thought I would create a new one.
So basically my environment is windows and I'm using cygwin.
I'm trying to install VTK. I have generated everything using Windows Cmake.
Now when i'm launching make I get the following output:

```
`make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg
[  6%] Creating directories for 'vtk-compile-tools'
[ 12%] No download step for 'vtk-compile-tools'
[ 18%] No patch step for 'vtk-compile-tools'
[ 25%] No update step for 'vtk-compile-tools'
[ 31%] Performing configure step for 'vtk-compile-tools'
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/cygwin64/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gmake.exe"
  "cmTryCompileExec4220576950/fast"

  gmake.exe[3]: Entering directory
  'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gmake.exe -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/build

  gmake.exe[4]: Entering directory
      'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  "C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
      C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

  C:/cygwin64/bin/cc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\cc, C:/cygwin64/bin/cc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c,
  ...) failed.

      make (e=5): Acc▒s refus▒.

      gmake.exe[4]: ***
      [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 5

  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target
  'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4220576950.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

  gmake.exe[4]: Leaving directory
  'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec4220576950/fast' failed

  gmake.exe[3]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4220576950/fast] Error 2

  gmake.exe[3]: Leaving directory
 'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-compile-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMakeFiles/vtk-compile-tools.dir/build.make:102 : la recette pour la cible « CMakeExternals/Prefix/vtk-compile-tools/src/vtk-compile-tools-stamp/vtk-compile-tools-configure » a échouée
make[2]: *** [CMakeExternals/Prefix/vtk-compile-tools/src/vtk-compile-tools-stamp/vtk-compile-tools-configure] Erreur 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95 : la recette pour la cible « CMakeFiles/vtk-compile-tools.dir/all » a échouée
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vtk-compile-tools.dir/all] Erreur 2
Makefile:75 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
make: *** [all] Erreur 2`
```

So I thought this could be linked to the fact that my configuring was done with windows cmake, so I tried to use cygwin cmake, but when I do I get the following error:

```
 cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
CMake Error at C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/VTK-6.2.0/CMakeLists.txt:28 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/VTK-6.2.0/CMakeLists.txt:28 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Now I know I'm a complete newbie to it all but I'm kinda stuck here and so far all that I've searched online doesn't help at all.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: If i configure to use /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe instead of /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe I do get the same kind of error, only the path is updated

```
 cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.1.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

 It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gmake.exe"
  "cmTryCompileExec1614361486/fast"

  C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gmake -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/build

  gmake[1]: Entering directory
  'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report
  /cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target
  'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' failed

  gmake[1]: Leaving directory
  'C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  gcc.exe: error:
  /cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c:
  No such file or directory

  gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

  compilation terminated.

  gmake[1]: ***     [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1614361486.dir/testCCompiler.c.o]
 Error 1

      Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec1614361486/fast' failed

  gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec1614361486/fast] Error 2


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/VTK-6.2.0/CMakeLists.txt:28 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/Lonni/VTK/VTK-6.2.0/CMakeLists.txt:28 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm guessing I need to do something with the path, but I don't know if that's really the solution. Here is my path anyway if needed

```
 echo $PATH
 /usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MicrosoftMPI/Bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/doxygen/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/Dev Utilities/gluegen/gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64/gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64/jar/gluegen-rt.jar:/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/Dev Utilities/jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64/jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64/jar/atomic/jogl.jar:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Tcl/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/doxygen/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/Dev Utilities/gluegen/gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64/gluegen-2.3-b858-20150410-windows-amd64/jar/gluegen-rt.jar:/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/Dev Utilities/jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64/jogl-2.3-b1392-20150410-windows-amd64/jar/atomic/jogl.jar:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/usr/lib/lapack
```

Comment: Does `C:/cygwin64/bin/cc` exist? Does `C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe` exist?

Comment: If you configure the second example as `/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe` instead of `C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gcc.exe` it might work. The former is clearly having a permissions issue with something but isn't clear about what. If you run the command manually does it tell you more about what is going on?

Comment: Questions updated with that

Comment: Does `/cygdrive/c/Users/Lonni/VTK/BuildCyg2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c` exist? (I would expect cmake to create that on the fly so it may not now but should during the test.)

Comment: No it doesn't exist. But I guess it would be created after all the tests that fail in the first place no?

Comment: That should be created by cmake during the test process since the compilation test needs it. If that isn't happening for some reason that would be a problem.

Comment: Isn't it because it reckons that the c compiler is broken?

Comment: It determines that the compiler is broken because the compiler fails to compile that test file.

Comment: Oh I see. So would you happen to know why this file is not created at all?

Comment: I don't know that it isn't. I'm guessing it might not be. I don't know what's going on offhand. You could try using procmon (from the SysInternals tools) if you wanted to see what was really happening under the covers but that's very low level. You might be able to get more info from cmake with a debug flag/argument but I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried with the debug flag and it gives exactly the same result :(

Comment: Which is your environment? Windows? Linux? Which flavour? What about using mingw instead?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is the system that I'm using. Unfortunately I cannot use mingw

Comment: Up anyone? ^^' :) :)

Comment: For some reason, CMake under Cygwin in Windows 10 is not able to create the temporary files it needs for the build process. I am just trying to figure out why. Same issue here: https://github.com/OpenFAST/openfast/issues/108

Answer (score 0):

For cywin make: Just move the sources you want to build to the cygwin directory or some subfolder (e.g.: "c:\cygwin64\some_dir").